# Renault kwid 0.8 1st gear idle speed issue

Tags: gears, renault

I own a a Renault kwid 0.8 4 wheeler.it is my first car and it is used car. I don't have prior experience in owning a car.

I have noticed that in 1st gear without giving any gas the speed is reaching around 20km/h. Is it normal? I had learnt driving many years ago and as far I can recall it was not idling that speed.

In the dashboard it has a gear shift indicator. Sometimes it signals to downshift even on 1st gear.

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not really sure what your question is .. hoping you can clarify so we can help you.

Comment: Are you saying that in 1st gear, it will drive at 20kmh without your foot on the throttle?  Does the vehicle have a rev counter?

Comment: @HandyHowie yes, correct. One more thing I have noticed. Once I drive it on third gear and then move to 2nd then it starting to drive it in normal speed at 2nd gear.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thanks. The problem.is it seems like the car is idling at much higher speed on 1st and 2nd gear than it should be according to me.

Comment: @HandyHowie the Vehicle does not have rev counter but it has gear shift indicator.